# Create universal app *.WINMD and *.DLL for distribution i.e. to be referenced like the Universal app API

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I want to create WINMD file from my project which should work like `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd` in the universal app API so that I can simply reference them instead of building the runtime project again and again after setting up new development machines. Think of this as releasing a *.dll (and other files) that one can reuse without recompile everything from source. How can I set up my project in Visual Studio to achieve that? Note that the WINMD should be somehow cross-platform i.e. usable for x86 and ARM alike. (I am sorry that this is not a programming-related question. But I am not so sure where to ask such thing.)

To put it another way, how do I reference the output of my Windows Runtime Component project (i.e. those `*.dll`, `*.winmd`, `*.lib`, `*.pdb`, ... in `Debug` or `Release` folder) compiled by Visual Studio directly **just like loading a DLL and using the library via appropriate header files in classical C/C++** without adding the Windows Runtime Component project source code to my solution and "Add reference" it where Visual Studio automatically recompiles it as necessary?

Comment: New Project->Universal->Windows Runtime Component

Comment: @tao The problem is to build the Windows Runtime Component (WRC) so that I can just "copy" it to my main app project just like installing/loading a *.dll with appropriate header files in classical C/C++ instead of doing "Add reference" to the WRC project in Visual Studio where I need to re-compile the WRC again when moving to new computer, for instance. How do I add the compiled output of WRC?

Comment: You are asking for a way to create DLL Hell.  You can't, WinRT puts a stop to that.  Only blessed components can do this, no way you'll get the required certificate.  Dependencies must be embedded in the application package.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think there is a DLL hell here and the dependencies are still included in the app package: what I ask for is more like static library `*.lib`. In this case, I want to somehow make sure that Visual Studio add my build-once-and-reuse `*.dll` everytime it need to rebuild the app instead of re-compiling the `*.dll` over and over again. (The terminology is a bit messy here.)

Comment: @VuAnHoa Visual Studio will not recompile projects that have not change since the last build.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek It is not a problem for a single machine. The problem occurs when you have to distribute the project over multiple machines to be developed as a team. It is not very great for everybody to spend a few hours on recompilation while I can compile once and copy over to other machines and people can jump start right away, isn't it?

Comment: @VuAnHoa I'm not familiar with the problem you have and don't understand why (and how) would VS rebuild already built files? If you add it like reference via Browse (not Solution Project) it should do what you want - just use already built one instead of recompiling it. The cross-platform thing is not supported anymore with UWP (there is no AnyCPU by default; this can, maybe, be configured manually) if I'm not mistaking, you need to build it for every platform.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek Yes, adding the reference via `Browse` should work; though it would be a nuisance to remove and add reference again to build for different architecture. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214446/referencing-native-c-dll-in-c-windows-app-only-works-when-added-as-reference?rq=1 seems to provide a way to include *.dll when deploying.